# Screen Mirroring error : Green screen with audio

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, xposed-framework, screencast, miracast, screen-mirroring

My device is **lyf flame 1 {Ls-4503}** android 5.1

[image: about phone]

There is no wireless display or screen mirroring option in it.However when i use playstore app like miracast or ezmira ,i see this option

[image: cast screen]

Clicking on the device, **it gets connected but i see only a green screen on my tv** .I can hear the audio,but **there is no video only green screen**.

[image: green screen]

In the setting menu,i clicked on the devoloper option and turned on the **wireless display certificate**

[image: Cast screen]

In order to find solution, i rooted my phone to instll a custom rom, but my bad luck!, there is no custom rom available for my phone.I installed **Xposed Framework**,but i found no module to fix this problem.Also there is no twrp recovery available for my phone,so i can not go for magisk module.

**Note:** The anycast device is working properly.I connected my laptop and it was working perfectly

Help me to find a solution for the green screen problem.Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and tried to reinstall/update the display driver = Intel(R) UHD Graphic 620 at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/126790/Intel-UHD-Graphics-630.

It's 100% solved. Microsoft issues.